# Avoid duplicate "pairs" of values (two columns) in a SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table documenting relationships between household members, and I'd like to  make sure there will always be only one record with the same two people in it -- but there are now two columns and two values to consider. I've done a couple hours of searching and while I'm sure it's out there I haven't found it.

I have a table for people whose foreign key (Persons.ID) here would appear in aID and bID (two people). I have another table for roles (mother, daughter, uncle, sibling, etc...) whose foreign key (Roles.ID) would appear in aID_role and bID_role). (I'm trying to store only integers in this table, because it might eventually have quite a few records.)

```
Relationships
----------------------------------------
aID     aID_role     bID     bID_role
----------------------------------------
 4        1           5        2
```

Say aID 4 is John and and bID 5 is Carla. aID_role 1 is "father" and bID_role 2 is "daughter".

How do I prevent the second record below being entered?

```
Relationships
----------------------------------------
aID     aID_role     bID     bID_role
----------------------------------------
 4        1           5        2
 5        2           4        1 <-- sort of a duplicate
```

Please note that I'm not interested in comparing the "_role" columns. They're nonmaterial here; I want to avoid Person.IDs 4 and 5 from appearing in more than one record in the Relationships table.

Database is in Azure SQL.

Comment: You want a check constraint (etc) or a query to check for possible duplicates?

Comment: Thanks Salman: I assume that's what I should do, but I struggled with how. I attempted something like "ALTER TABLE Relationship ADD CONSTRAINT ChkPair  ...", but I couldn't figure out how to get the constraint to check for _two_ values against _two_ columns.

Comment: Are you sure you're modelling roles correctly here? Isn't the role a property of the relationship as a whole, rather than of one or other party? I.e. If `b` is `daughter` of `a`, why would you expect anything *other* that `father` in the other position?

Comment: Thanks Damien. No, I'm really not sure at all this is the best way to model roles. But we needed to be able to tell not just what the relationship is, but who is who in the relationship. (If it's just "parent", then who is the parent?) So it _seemed_ to make sense to store the role for each person in the relationship. I dug around the nets on this issue as well, and didn't find much. If there's a better way to model relationships, I'm certainly keen for it.

Comment: show how you enter the records in the Relationship table (SQL)

Comment: Mike, is it always a `1:1` relationship, or do you want to store something like a *group of friends* too? Does your person table know the person's sex? In this case you can translate *parent* to *father* or *mother* rather easily. One quick suggestion: Define one more table with **directed relationships** like (*parent-of* or even *father-of-a-daughter*) and reduce your table to three columns, where you force the person's ID to `a` and `b` in the relationship's direction...

Comment: Thomas, I'm just using a simple insert statement: `insert into Relationships (aID, aID_role, bID, bID_role) VALUES (4,1,5,4);`.
I'm going to give Damien's answer below a go; that seems like a winner. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Shnugo. It's always a `1:1` relationship. If I use directed relationships, I will either have twice the records in the table or will have to have extra code that extrapolates the inverse relationship (maybe that's not a bad thing).

Comment: Mike, one possible enhancement might be (if you need this) to create your Relationship-table with a nullable column `IsOppositeOf`. This would allow for the user to pick *father-of* or *child-of* out of a selection. While storing this data you should use the *leading relationship* (with a NULL in this column) only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create computed columns that mirror the ids like so:

```
id1 AS (CASE WHEN aID < bID THEN aid ELSE bid END),
id2 AS (CASE WHEN aID < bID THEN bid ELSE aid END),
```

Then the two *duplicate* rows would look like:

```
aID  bID  id1  id2
4    5    4    5
5    4    4    5
```

And you just need to create a UNIQUE constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT IX_Relationships UNIQUE (id1, id2)
```

Comment: This looks great! How can I compare this method with the method Damien proposed in his answer to see which one is less costly to the server?

Comment: You can tune either solutions for performance (computed columns could be indexed I believe).

Comment: @MikeNoviskie . . . This version is simpler.  Damien's solution requires creating a separate table in the database for the unique constraint.  This solution just involves changes to the one table that needs the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to prevent the "opposite" row from being inserted, you need to implement a unique constraint on a pair of columns which are guaranteed a particular property (e.g. that the first is always lower than the second).

For non-directed graphs, a simple approach is a check constraint on the table and then ensuring the data gets inserted to match the constraint.

However, relationships tend to be *directed* relationships. E.g. I would have a table with `FromID`, `ToID` and `Relationship` where the latter would be a lookup to values such as "Father to Daughter" (which you can read with an implicit "From" at the start) which makes clear which is the `FromID` and which is the `ToID`.

Such a structure makes clear that there's only one right way around for these relationships to be stored - but you may still not be able to guarantee that e.g. `FromID` is always lower that `ToID` and may wish to prevent accidental insertions that are incorrect (prevent someone being simultaneously the mother and daughter of someone else)

So we introduce an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) that synthesizes a pair of columns with this relationship and then place the unique constraint on it.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Relationships_DRI_Unique
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
         CASE WHEN FromID < ToID THEN FromID ELSE ToID   END as Col1,
         CASE WHEN FromID < ToID THEN ToID   ELSE FromID END as Col2
    FROM
        dbo.Relationships
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Relationships_DRI_Unique on dbo.Relationships_DRI_Unique (Col1,Col2)
```

(`DRI` = Declarative Referential Integrity. It's my own convention to use those letters in naming objects that exist purely to enforce a constraint. I don't expect anyone will ever *query* this view)

Answer (score 0):

proposition of new model:

```
table persons
id PK
first_name,
second_name


table roles
id PK
role_id
role_name (ex. Father, daugther,)

table relationship
id PK
person    (ex. persons.id = 1, JOHN)
role      (roles.id = 5, FATHER
person_to (persons.id = 3, CARLA,
```

so in short "person" is "role" to "person_to".

Example from your question: You only have to add 1 record into table relationship for:

"JOHN" is "FATHER" to "CARLA.

there is no need to add second LIKE

"CARLA" is "daughter" of "JOHN"

Comment: Thanks! While this looks simpler, how would I enforce data integrity? What would prevent someone later entering an record for "Carla is daughter of John" (unnecessary extra record, as you point out), or worse "Carla is cousin of John" (they made the wrong selection). Now we have two records that are in conflict with one another. That's why I'm needing to prevent the "duplicate pairs" thing: Carla's ID and John's ID must appear together in a record only once in the entire table--regardless of whether I use a directed relationship or store both roles.

Comment: Second scenario - think about UNIQUE constraint on columns "person" and "person_to". In this case - if Carla is daugher of john record exists, then record Carla is cousin of john will cause error.

First scenario - This could be done by a trigger "BEFORE STATEMENT" to check if any relationship between this two persons exists. But be careful - If this table grows big, and full scan will be required berfore any insert/update, this could cause performance issue. Think about some indexes.